# Android Why I go on a view, the keyboard open

Tags: android, view, keyboard, android-edittext

When I go on a view, the keyboard open automaticaly on the first editText and my view is on a scrollView.

My editText:

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="@string/nom"
            android:ems="25"
            android:id="@+id/etNom"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_custom"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

to prevent opening at start.
You can also request focus from other view, if wanted.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, But this doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

The answer:
I put this on my LinearLayout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```